# Node and Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with my Visual Studio.

Every time I run my Node.js code in Visual Studio I get an error.

```
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\Code\AalBot\index.js:1:79)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:733:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
```

I tried to reinstall Node with `node install` but it don't work

```
    npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Markus\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Markus\package.json'
npm WARN Markus No description
npm WARN Markus No repository field.
npm WARN Markus No README data
npm WARN Markus No license field.

up to date in 1.901s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I tried also `npm install` but it also doesn't work

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Markus\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Markus\package.json'
npm WARN Markus No description
npm WARN Markus No repository field.
npm WARN Markus No README data
npm WARN Markus No license field.

up to date in 1.901s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

This is my Npm Version when I type `npm version` in

```
    { npm: '6.4.1',
  ares: '1.15.0',
  cldr: '34.0',
  http_parser: '2.8.0',
  icu: '63.1',
  modules: '67',
  napi: '3',
  nghttp2: '1.34.0',
  node: '11.2.0',
  openssl: '1.1.0i',
  tz: '2018e',
  unicode: '11.0',
  uv: '1.23.2',
  v8: '7.0.276.38-node.11',
  zlib: '1.2.11' }
```

I hope you guys can help me, when you need more info, tell me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using *require('discord.js')*, and npm is waiting for a npm module with that name.

If you want to import a module use

> require('discord')

if it's a file

> require('./discord.js')

Comment: NPM packages can have `.js` in their name. In fact from https://discord.js.org/#/, their setup guide states `const Discord = require('discord.js');`.

Comment: Can have .js but it can't be a relative path

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `npm install` in the directory where your app lives. From the error message, it looks like you are running it from your home folder (which could of course be your app directory but I would assume not :)).

Edit: to be clear, run `npm install` in your app root directory, where `package.json` is located.